# Facebook doesn't notify users of comments to posts by apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've found what could be a glaring problem with Facebook, or it could be a misunderstanding on my part (hope it's the latter). I have an app that uses the graph API to post links to friends walls (friends of the user, that is). The problem is that if the friend comments on the post, the user is never notified of it. i.e. Facebook doesn't create a notification for my user that his friend has commented on his post. That's a significant issue if you're trying to build an app that focuses on link sharing! *Important:* I've checked my notification settings several times, and I have the most liberal settings but still do  not get any notifications.

It must be that Facebook treats posts by apps [differently](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/365/). My questions are:

1) Has anyone experienced a similar issue, or is there some way to get these notifications of comments to work?

2) If this is an inherent limitation, is there a way that my app can pick up on comments in response to posts made by my app? I can probably save the post id and regularly check back for comments...but that sucks. A better way would be to subscribe to changes in the post, although it doesn't look like [Facebook's real-time updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) support this. Maybe I'm answering my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has acknowledged that this is a bug.  The bug report and response by Facebook can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/305201532846556).  Facebook has assigned it as a Medium priority issue...